# How to give Jenkins more heap space when it´s started as a service?

Tags: jenkins, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I want to increase the available heap space for Jenkins. But as it is installed as a service I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In your Jenkins installation directory there is a jenkins.xml, where you can set various options.
Add the parameter -Xmx with the size you want to the arguments-tag (or increase the size if its already there).

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu

Comment: my question is : if the builds is running out of memory , why we should set the java options in the master ?

Comment: You shouldn't. But this question was not about builds running out of memory, it was about master running out of memory.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, there's no such file. The `/etc/default/jenkins` solution offered below by Steve is the one that works for me.

Comment: So if the build step of a jenkins job is failing with this error, then java opts should be set for the jenkins SLAVE, right?

Answer (score 122):

If you used Aptitude (apt-get) to install Jenkins on Ubuntu 12.04, uncomment the `JAVA_ARGS` line in the top few lines of `/etc/default/jenkins`:

```
# arguments to pass to java
#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"   # <--default value
JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx2048m"
#JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" # make jenkins listen on IPv4 address
```

Comment: what if it's windows?

Comment: Question specifically states Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this answer before I knew what I was doing on SO, and I'm surprised that it's gotten so many upvotes. Perhaps, like me, a lot of people find their way to this question through a search engine, and a larger percentage of those people are using Linux or Unix? I don't understand it.

Comment: "Perhaps, like me, a lot of people find their way to this question through a search engine, and a larger percentage of those people are using Linux or Unix? I don't understand it." That's exactly how I found it.

Comment: Don't forget restart jenkins service `sudo service jenkins stop`  `sudo service jenkins start`

Comment: We should edit the question to include linux servers, as the majority of servers run some form of linux OS, and not windows, and since this answer has the most up votes.

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/jenkins for centos 7

Comment: Warning! After Jenkins 2.332.1 the `/etc/default/jenkins` config file is ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494231/jenkins-changes-in-etc-default-jenkins-not-working

Answer (score 79):

You need to modify the [jenkins.xml](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/windows-service/jenkins.xml) file. Specifically you need to change

```
   <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m 
    -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle 
    -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

to

```
    <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
    -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle 
    -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

You can also verify the Java options that Jenkins is using by installing the [Jenkins monitor plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring) via **Manage Jenkins** / **Manage Plugins** and then navigating to **Managing Jenkins** / **Monitoring of Hudson** / **Jenkins master** to use monitoring to determine how much memory is available to Jenkins.

If you are getting an out of memory error when Jenkins calls Maven, it may be necessary to set MAVEN_OPTS via **Manage Jenkins** / **Configure System** e.g. if you are running on a version of Java prior to JDK 1.8 (the values are suggestions):

```
-Xmx2048m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

If you are using JDK 1.8:

```
-Xmx2048m
```

Comment: when i try setting the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS as described above i get: "Starting Jenkins Unrecognized option: --XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

Comment: There should be only one hyphen: `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` - the above response has been edited to fix this typo.

Comment: Any idea how to set JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS in Windows?

Comment: On Windows, according to http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-set-JENKINS-JAVA-OPTIONS-under-Windows-Exception-URI-must-start-with-a-slash-td3426304.html you use Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Comment: `-XX:MaxPermSize` is no longer used with Java 8 or higher https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114174/what-does-xxmaxpermsize-do

Answer (score 39):

I've added to **/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** (CentOS):

```
# Options to pass to java when running Jenkins.
#
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

For ubuntu the same config should be located in **/etc/default**

Answer (score 16):

From the Jenkins wiki:

> The JVM launch parameters of these
>   Windows services are controlled by an
>   XML file jenkins.xml and
>   jenkins-slave.xml respectively. These
>   files can be found in $JENKINS_HOME
>   and in the slave root directory
>   respectively, after you've install
>   them as Windows services.
>
> The file format should be
>   self-explanatory. Tweak the arguments
>   for example to give JVM a bigger
>   memory.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service