# JVM Creation Failed Message when opening netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

My Netbeans works perfectly until today. But today morning when try to open net beans it gives the **JVM creation failed message.**

Comment: Try to add the complete failed message in the question!

Comment: It is the Full message.

Comment: in my case i was playing with the `jvm.dll in java\jre7\bin\client` i replaced it  so oracle jinitiator for oracle forms will work according to some blog it worked but netbeans broke then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open netbeans.conf file under C:\Program Files\NetBeans\etc
2. Find this row:

`netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"`

3. And replace with this: added **XX:MaxPermSize=128m**

`netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"`

4. Restart NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks it works but can you explain problem behind this fail and how this problem solve by replacing this netbeans_default_options ?

Comment: You can find info about XX:MaxPermSize http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114174/what-does-xxmaxpermsize-do