# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea

When I'mtrying to open Intellij IDE using command line in linux like this `./phpstorm.sh` both android studio and PHPStorm I always got this message :

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;
>   support was removed in 8.0

and I was wondering if google find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634689/2652524) but I was kinda lost here since I'm newbie in ubuntu 14.04. my question is what is the cause of this message to diplay? and how to resolve this?

I've tried using this command `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m"` but it's not resolve the issue.
and I'm using `java 1.8.0_73` downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). any useful help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are using an option which was removed in Java 8 and will be ignored, as the message states. You can either ignore the warning or remove the option.

Comment: @PeterLawrey removing the option means I remove the option MaxPermSize=350m ?

Comment: Yes, it's not going to do anything except cause a little confusion. Have a look at your `idea64.vmoptions`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is only a warning saying the option has been ignored - so it should not cause any issues.

The JVM options should be located in {IntelliJ folder}/bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions (on windows - probably something similar on linux). You can edit that file and delete the maxpermsize option.

Comment: yes removing the maxpermsize option the message will not appear again

Answer (score 2):

The IDEs try to set MaxPermSize in case the are run under java 7.
The parameter was removed in java 8, so it is ignored.

For further information see [What does -XX:MaxPermSize do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114174/what-does-xxmaxpermsize-do)

Answer (score 0):

For me I fixed same issue by adding _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx6G to the enviroment variable
Windows 8.1
java version 1.7.0_79

Answer (score 0):

if you got this error with android studio using phonegap so just exit from android studio and restart android studio some time its work in my case