# Related with Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-18.04

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0

How to solve this issue in ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500968/openjdk-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize-350m)

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.