# while running jenkins build I am getting java heap space error

Tags: maven, jenkins

```java
Exception in thread "ThreadedStreamConsumer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.TestSetRunListener.getAsString(TestSetRunListener.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.TestSetRunListener.wrap(TestSetRunListener.java:228)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.TestSetRunListener.testFailed(TestSetRunListener.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.consumeLine(ForkClient.java:114)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:67)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: how to increase heap size in jenkins,the jenkins is in linux machin, but i am not able to find its directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu

Comment: need to know the causes for java heap space error,in out project we are using logging functionality.is this a one of cause ?

Comment: Maybe it's just a plugin requesting more memory to perform some operation. It's not something unusual for java apps.

Comment: in pom.xml there <argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -ea</argLine>still it is giving problem