# What is the max # of jobs you have run on Jenkins concurrently, and what were the system specs of your server, and what are your CATALINA_OPTS?

Tags: tomcat, memory, memory-management, jenkins, out-of-memory

What is the max # of jobs you have run on Jenkins concurrently, and what were the system specs of your server, and what are your CATALINA_OPTS?

We're encountering issues where we're unable to access the Jenkins front-end with the following specs. Wondering if anyone else has experienced similar issues and how you resolved it?

~500 jobs queued up
16G 4 Cores 10796 MHz (10 GHz or 2.5 GHz per CPU) CentOS-5 2 Ggz CPU

Catalina ops:
/usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -XX:PermSize=10G -XX:MaxPermSize=10G -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat7/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Answer (score 0):

are you using any slaves? in our setup, we dont run any regular jobs on master, we use 7 slaves with 4 executors on each, so the max job we run is 28.

Looking at your heap size setting, 10G for permgen is quite odd, do you meant to set max heap size to 10g? have a look at this: [How do I give Jenkins more heap space when it's running as a daemon on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu)

Next time when your jenkins is hanging, do a kill -3 on the server, you might find some clue from the threaddump.