# Out of memory - java heap space error from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, out-of-memory

I am running a job from Jenkins and the job throws out of memory- java heap space error. But if I run the same job directly on the server manually it runs fine.

Both use `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/` and `apache-maven-3.0.5`. This is on Linux.

I tried setting `MAVEN_OPTS` with various permutations and combinations of
`-Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=3g` but nothing helps.

I have only a total of 8G in the system.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: MAVEN_OPTS won't make a difference, you have to give it a bigger heap size as a java arg: jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors `JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx1048m"`

Comment: Cole9350: The link that you provided says that the -Xmx settings is through MAVEN_OPTS. If you say MAVEN_OPTS is not going to make a difference, where do you suggest that I add JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx1048m" in Jenkins?

Comment: MAVEN_OPTS will increase the memory on the build level but will not let you exceed maximum memory allocated for jenkins in the first place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu