# jenkines gat stuck at sonar-qube analysis. The analysis and successfully, but the job stuck

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

Im running sonar in Jenkins job. The analysis stage end successfully, but after that, the job get stuck, there is nothing in the log, but after a few min I get out off memory error and the job fails.

my sonar property file:

```
sonar.language=javascript

# sources
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**

# tests
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.test.js

# tests reports
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/test-reporter.xml
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info

sonar.verbose=true
```

the log:

```
13:31:10  13:31:10.683 INFO: Analysis report generated in 522ms, dir size=4 MB
13:31:12  13:31:12.797 INFO: Analysis report compressed in 2114ms, zip size=2 MB
13:31:12  13:31:12.797 INFO: Analysis report generated in /my_reports_loc
13:31:12  13:31:12.797 DEBUG: Upload report
13:31:12  13:31:12.955 DEBUG: POST 200 http://my-sonar/api/ce/submit?projectKeymyProjt&projectName=projectNamet | time=157ms
13:31:12  13:31:12.958 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 161ms
13:31:12  13:31:12.959 DEBUG: Report metadata written to /my_reports_loc
13:31:12  13:31:12.959 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://my-sonar/dashboard?id=my-project
13:31:12  13:31:12.959 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
13:31:12  13:31:12.959 INFO: More about the report processing at http://my-sonar/api/ce/task?id=my_id
13:31:12  13:31:12.964 DEBUG: eslint-bridge server will shutdown
13:31:13  13:31:13.208 DEBUG: stylelint-bridge server will shutdown
13:31:13  13:31:13.209 INFO: Analysis total time: 42.940 s
13:31:13  13:31:13.230 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:13  13:31:13.230 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
13:31:13  13:31:13.230 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:13  13:31:13.230 INFO: Total time: 44.469s
13:31:13  13:31:13.369 INFO: Final Memory: 43M/1106M
13:31:13  13:31:13.369 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // 
13:33:47 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the Heap Size.

The error about GC overhead implies that Jenkins is thrashing in Garbage Collection. This means it's probably spending more time doing Garbage Collection than doing useful work. This situation normally comes about when the heap is too small for the application.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu/14762164#:%7E:text=To%20add%20more%20Java%20heap,else%20if%20you%20want%20more.) will help you in case if you need to know, how to increase help size for jenkins.