# Jenkins not starting up in redhat linux due to OOM-Kill

Tags: jenkins, memory-management

I started an aws ec2 instance and it is running jenkins on it. It was running fine but automatically stopped running from few days.
I diagnosed the problem using dmesg and I got the following error

```
 oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/jenkins.service,task=java,pid=1168,uid=993
[233949.461595] Out of memory: Killed process 1168 (java) total-vm:2251668kB, anon-rss:317444kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:993
[233949.566855] oom_reaper: reaped process 1168 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-74 ~]$ ^C
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-74 ~]$ ps -f 1168
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
```

The solutions I found online were to edit jenkins.xml in /var/lib/jenkins. But I cant find jenkins.xml instead I have config.xml

```
?xml version='2.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors>
    <string>jenkins.diagnostics.RootUrlNotSetMonitor</string>
  </disabledAdministrativeMonitors>
  <version>2.263.4</version>
  <installStateName>RUNNING</installStateName>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
  </authorizationStrategy>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
    <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
    <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
  </securityRealm>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  <projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
  <jdks>
    <jdk>
      <name>Java</name>
      <home>/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-2.el8_3.x86_64</home>
      <properties/>
    </jdk>
  </jdks>
  <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  <myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
  <clouds/>
  <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
  <views>
    <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>all</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
  <primaryView>all</primaryView>
```

I am not sure how to decrease heap size or resolve the problem via any other solution.

Comment: Either increase RAM, add swap, or reduce jenkins memory via jvm settings.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you please guide? @DominikGebhart

Comment: If you want to increase your RAM you can upscale your instance from AWS console and upgrade to a higher tier instance type. If you think the amount of RAM available is not an issue and instead the issue is with the default heap memory allocated then you can try to increase it. See below link on how to increase heap size for jenkins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762162/how-do-i-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-running-as-a-daemon-on-ubuntu/14762164#:~:text=java.-,lang.,java.&text=OutOfMemoryError%3A%20PermGen%20space%20%E2%80%93%20this%20means,to%20store%20Java%20object%20metadata.