# Jenkins consumes a very large portion of physical memory

Tags: memory-management, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on a virtual OS. Whenever I start the Jenkins service the physical memory goes up to 94%. Then it never reduces. So my system becomes very slow and unresponsive. As a result the Jenkins web page becomes slow. I have allocated 4GB for RAM. Is there any way to speed up my machine to restrict the memory use for Jenkins?

Comment: your java version? and your OS

Comment: Memory usage of Jenkins is controlled by the memory settings of the JVM, if using Ubuntu/Debian linux, this is defined in /etc/default/jenkins

Comment: i am using jenkins in Win7 with java7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give Jenkins more heap space when it´s started as a service under Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-it%c2%b4s-started-as-a-service-under-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jenkins on the same virtual machine as critical application, is it wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633415/jenkins-on-the-same-virtual-machine-as-critical-application-is-it-wise)

Comment: YOu need to configure Xmx and Xms in jenkins.xml file to fit's your server memory size.