# jenkins on the same virtual machine as critical application, is it wise?

Tags: jenkins

I want to use Jenkins to automate tasks belonging to a web application running on tomcat on the same server.

As the application is quite critical, is it wise to install Jenkins on the same Virtual machine?
There will be 2  JVM running on the same Virtual Machine, could be a problem in term of memory,cpu, stability etc?

Should I take care of something in particular or it would be better to install Jenkins on another Virtual Server?

Answer (score 1):

> As the application is quite critical, is it wise to install Jenkins on the same Virtual machine?

No, it's not wise. If you are already in a virtualized environment, create a new VM for Jenkins (but at least separate it, e.g., run your prod and jenkins in two different docker containers). Why is it not wise apart from performance? Your tests may even crash the VM if you are unlucky. Or they can eat away your resources (file locks, network ports, etc.). Or Jenkins can overwrite your productive code if you did not set it up properly (e.g., deploys into the same folder where your prod is).

> There will be 2 JVM running on the same Virtual Machine, could be a problem in term of memory,cpu, stability etc?

Of course it will be a performance problem, but not because of the 2 JVMs, but because of the tests themselves (if you have a bigger project with a lot of tests, that eats performance away most probably).

> Should I take care of something in particular or it would be better to install Jenkins on another Virtual Server?

Just run it in another VM; even better another physical machine (if you are in a hosted environment e.g., AWS, then disregard the last point).

> Edit: adding crucial information "it will just replace cron"

Yeah, in this case it should be OK. Jenkins itself does not use too many resources (otherwise it wouldn't be as well usable for a build server/**scheduler**), and about the worries for the additional JVM: I have seen many production environments where there are dozens of JVMs running in parallel. It all comes down to the individual scenarious: what are these production stuff doing? (Heavy I/O? Heavy networking? Just listening for occasinally serving a REST resource? Idly collecting randomness from the ether?) And again: what are your specs for the VM and the hardware on which it is running... this is a very complex question, which depends on:

- the software/service
- the OS (yes, it does matter whether it's Ubuntu, RedHat, SUSE, etc.)
- the VM parameters (how much VCPUs does it have? How much VRAM? Is it KVM based or VMWare, something else?)
- the hardware underneath (is it crafty enough? What are your over/underprovisioning ratios? Does your network bear the load?)

It's a question where all departments (Infra, DevOps, SE, etc.) has to work together.

Comment: actually Jenkins will substitute cron. There is no extra load on the Application server due to tasks, that will be the normal load. But Jenkins will add its own overhead to the VM. I'm not sure how much will that be.

Comment: Jenkins itself is pretty low on resource usage (minimum recommended RAM for example is 200 MB). It all comes down to: what are you using it for? If you are building huge Java projects with maven, and unit/integration testing them then it could produce a huge load (not Jenkins itself but what you are running with it). If you just want to use it as a scheduler though... still it depends what will you do with it? Every 24 hours an apt-get update/upgrade? Should be OK. Every 10 min an `rm -rf /tmp`? Could go wrong, depending on what is in `tmp` for your production env...