# Could not reserve enough space for object heap error in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jvm, heap-memory

I am using jenkins to deploy my java project. But I am keep getting bellow error for particulate project.

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The server you are running Jenkins on does not have enough memory to support the default settings. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-started-as-a-service-under-windows) for more information on how to adjust (lower in your case) the amount of memory Jenkins uses.