# Unable to clone Bit Bucket repository using Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins' job to clone, build and deploy the code on tomcat server. But every time I run the job it ends exactly after 10 mins with same error

```
10:57:59 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
10:57:59 [DeployPublisher][INFO] Build failed, project not deployed
10:57:59 Finished: FAILURE
```

I know the root cause which is timeout is set to 10 min by default while jenkins job triggers the clone command

```
10:47:57  > git.exe --version # timeout=10
10:47:58  > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- repository-url +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
10:57:58 ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
10:57:59 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

What I couldn't figure out is how to increase this default timeout.
Followings are the list of Git plugins that I have been using
[Plugins used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inaqw.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into Jenkins documentation and found few Keywords and searching with them, ends up to the answer of my question.

Please refer to [this for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954727/jenkins-time-out-while-fetching-from-github-in-10-mins)