# Heap Space Error in jenkins

Tags: memory-management, jenkins, heap-memory

I'm facing below problem in my jenkins. How to get rid of this error?

> Status Code: 500
>   Exception: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.478.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:91:72:  Java heap space

Stacktrace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.478.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:91:72: <st:include> Java heap space
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:563)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:488)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:162)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.478.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:91:72: <st:include> Java heap space
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:735)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:107)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 1):

The default amount of memory allocated to JVM heap is not enough for the way you use Jenkins. Something causes a lot of memory to be used.

The easiest way to solve it is to make the heap larger and keep increasing it until you have found a heap size that works for you.

The path names in the stack trace look like Windows paths, so maybe you are running Jenkins on Windows? Possibly [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-it%C2%B4s-started-as-a-service-under-windows) will tell you the details on how to increase the heap size.