# Jenkins does not start with -Xrs -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m (windows)

Tags: java, jenkins

My Jenkins does not want to start with parameters `-Xrs -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080`  in jenkins.xml file. I also added JENKINS_HOME variable to windows variables and set path to my jenkins folder `c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`. But it does not help. I see in the log file error

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why  do you expect it to be able to start?

Comment: Also I've added option in Global properties in Jenkins MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx1024m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: I looked at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-it%C2%B4s-started-as-a-service-under-windows/28740885#28740885

Comment: I want to size up JVM because of error in Jenkins [code]java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space[code] when I run my soap ui tests

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. When you run your tests inside jenkins a new process is spawned and your idea with setting `MAVEN_OPTS` inside jenkins is a good one. A way forward may be to run the test succesfully outside jenkins and then *copy* the setup to the jenkins build.

Comment: You should not set any options on the Jenkins invocation.  Instead adjust the job running your soap ui tests.

Comment: I need a report after running of tests. And I use free version of Soap UI. I use build file for running my created soap ui tests in jenkins. And now I have more tests and get error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Need to update JRE version of Jenkins in its folder. I just copied new files to its folder and replaced the same files) Now I can start Jenkins with option

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx2048m -  Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar   "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

Also I use soap ui api for running tests in Jenkins. I changed option

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties "-Dsoapui.home=%SOAPUI_HOME%\"
```

in testrunner.bat And now my tests are run correctly and there are no errors Perm Gen!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are using 32-bit JVM on Windows.  This has a heap limit of about 1.2 - 1.5 GB depending on what you have run before.

I suggest either limiting yourself to `-Xmx1200m` or use a 64-bit JVM.

If you increase the PermGen, you need to decrease the heap size as the amount of virtual memory you can have in 32-bit windows is limited.

Comment: I looked at `java -version` and it showed me that I use 64bit version: 
`java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: How can I increase size of JVM?

Comment: @takeshi85 and you are sure this is the version Jenkins is using, not one installed under the Jenkins directory?

Comment: I use the last version of jenkins `jenkins-1.599` Only one version I have

Comment: Should I install slave mod for Jenkins?

Comment: @takeshi85 many applications ship with their own version of java. Can you look in the program files to see if Jenkins does this?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I set option `JDK installations` for Jenkins to my own installed java

Comment: @takeshi85 what did you set the JVM for Jenkins to be.  This setting only changes which JDK to perform the individual builds under.

Comment: Ok, I set path to my java 1.8 and in project I can specify Java Option. Now I'm trying to build my project with this http://prntscr.com/6ajesl option