# Where do I put Java JVM options for Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I was provided these settings by vendor to help improve the performance of our jenkins

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

I did an ls on the java and it says java-1.8.0-amazon-correto.x86_64. Where do I put that? Do I just add that to our systemd service since that's how our jenkins is started?

Comment: I think you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519.  It is about setting jenkins heap options, but the approach applies to all options.

Comment: How do I close this since it's all good?

Comment: Done it for you.